DOMException [AbortError]: This operation was aborted
that error happens but it stops the code then it sends the message to the target channel 3 times
but ig that happens because the audio file big cuz it works fine with the small audio files theres any possible way to fix this issue?
error:
node:events:497
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^
DOMException [AbortError]: This operation was aborted
at new DOMException (node:internal/per_context/domexception:53:5)
at AbortController.abort (node:internal/abort_controller:391:18)
at Timeout. (E:\SRTCODES\SRT-Discord\node_modules@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:680:47)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
Emitted 'error' event on Client instance at:
at emitUnhandledRejectionOrErr (node:events:402:10)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21)
Node.js v20.14.0
code:

const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, AttachmentBuilder, EmbedBuilder, ActionRowBuilder, StringSelectMenuBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle, ModalBuilder, TextInputBuilder, TextInputStyle } = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const axios = require('axios');
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
const FormData = require('form-data');
const { GoogleAuth } = require('google-auth-library');
const { google } = require('googleapis');

// Define your bot token and channel IDs
const DISCORD_TOKEN = '';
const SPECIFIC_CHANNEL_ID = ''; // Replace with the specific channel ID
const LEAD_CHANNEL_ID = ''; // Replace with the channel ID where the lead form should be sent

// Google Sheets API Setup
const auth = new GoogleAuth({
    keyFile: 'credentials.json', // Ensure you have this file with the right permissions
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
});

const sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth });
const SHEET_ID = '';
const TAB_APPROVED = '';

// Set up the Discord client
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages] });

// Map to store temporary lead submissions
const leadSubmissions = new Map();

client.once('ready', async () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);

    // Create and send the embed message with the "Submit Lead" button
    const leadEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle('Submit a Lead')
        .setDescription('Click the button below to submit a lead.')
        .setColor(0x00ff00);

    const leadButton = new ActionRowBuilder()
        .addComponents(
            new ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId('submitRecord')
                .setLabel('Submit Lead')
                .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary)
        );

    const leadChannel = client.channels.cache.get(LEAD_CHANNEL_ID);
    await leadChannel.send({ embeds: [leadEmbed], components: [leadButton] });
});

// Handle button interaction to display the lead submission modal
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (interaction.isButton() && interaction.customId === 'submitRecord') {
        const modal = new ModalBuilder()
            .setCustomId('leadFormModal1') // Unique ID for this modal
            .setTitle('Lead Submission Form');

        const nameInput = new TextInputBuilder()
            .setCustomId('name')
            .setLabel('Name')
            .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short);

        const whatsappInput = new TextInputBuilder()
            .setCustomId('whatsapp')
            .setLabel('WhatsApp Number')
            .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short);

        const emailInput = new TextInputBuilder()
            .setCustomId('email')
            .setLabel('Email')
            .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short);

        const ageInput = new TextInputBuilder()
            .setCustomId('age')
            .setLabel('Age')
            .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short);

        const gradInput = new TextInputBuilder()
            .setCustomId('grad')
            .setLabel('Grad (Answer with Yes or No)')
            .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short);

        const modalComponents = [
            new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(nameInput),
            new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(whatsappInput),
            new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(emailInput),
            new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(ageInput),
            new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(gradInput)
        ];

        modal.addComponents(modalComponents);
        await interaction.showModal(modal);
    }

    // Handle modal submission
    if (interaction.isModalSubmit() && interaction.customId === 'leadFormModal1') {
        const userId = interaction.user.id;
        const leadData = {
            name: interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('name'),
            whatsapp: interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('whatsapp'),
            email: interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('email'),
            age: interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('age'),
            grad: interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('grad'),
        };

        // Store lead data temporarily
        leadSubmissions.set(userId, leadData);

        const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(
                new StringSelectMenuBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('selectRole')
                    .setPlaceholder('Select a Role')
                    .addOptions([
                        { label: 'Real Estate Cold Caller', value: 'Real Estate Cold Caller' },
                        { label: 'Omnikom company', value: 'Omnikom Company' },
                        { label: 'SRT', value: 'SRT' },
                        { label: 'Nedialo', value: 'Nedialo' },
                        { label: 'TP', value: 'Tp' },
                        { label: 'Nothing', value: 'Nothing' },
                    ])
            );

        await interaction.reply({
            content: 'Please select one of the following roles:',
            components: [row],
            ephemeral: true,
        });
    } else if (interaction.isStringSelectMenu() && interaction.customId === 'selectRole') {
        const userId = interaction.user.id;
        const selectedValue = interaction.values[0];
        const leadData = leadSubmissions.get(userId);
        if (leadData) {
            leadData.role = selectedValue;
            leadSubmissions.set(userId, leadData);

            await interaction.update({
                content: 'Please send a voice note for assessment.',
                components: [],
                ephemeral: true,
            });
        }
    }
});

// Handle voice note submission
client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;

    const userId = message.author.id;
    const leadData = leadSubmissions.get(userId);

    if (leadData && message.attachments.size > 0) {
        const attachment = message.attachments.first();
        const filePath = `./temp_${attachment.name}`;

        // Download the voice note
        const response = await axios.get(attachment.url, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });
        fs.writeFileSync(filePath, response.data);

        // Convert and resample the audio
        let wavFileName = filePath;
        if (!filePath.endsWith('.wav')) {
            wavFileName = 'voice_note.wav';
            await convertToWav(filePath, wavFileName);
            fs.unlinkSync(filePath); // Delete the original file if converted
        }

        const resampledFileName = wavFileName;
        
        // Delete the original WAV file
        message.delete();

        // Analyze the voice note using SpeechSuper API
        const analysisResult = await assessSpeech(resampledFileName, 'Introduce yourself in English.');
        

        // Combine lead data with analysis result
        leadData.analysisResult = analysisResult;
        leadSubmissions.delete(userId);

        // Send the combined data to the specific channel
        const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle('New Lead Submission')
            .setAuthor({ name: message.author.tag, iconURL: message.author.displayAvatarURL() })
            .addFields(
                { name: 'Name', value: leadData.name },
                { name: 'WhatsApp Number', value: leadData.whatsapp },
                { name: 'Email', value: leadData.email },
                { name: 'Age', value: leadData.age },
                { name: 'Grad', value: leadData.grad },
                { name: 'Role', value: leadData.role },
                { name: 'Overall CEFR Score', value: analysisResult.ielts_score.overall.toString() },
                { name: 'Pronunciation', value: analysisResult.ielts_score.pronunciation.toString() },
                { name: 'Fluency', value: analysisResult.ielts_score.fluency.toString() },
                { name: 'Grammar', value: analysisResult.ielts_score.grammar.toString() },
                { name: 'Coherence', value: analysisResult.ielts_score.coherence.toString() },
                { name: 'Vocabulary', value: analysisResult.ielts_score.vocabulary.toString() },
                { name: 'Transcription', value: analysisResult.transcription },
            );
        const audioFile = new AttachmentBuilder(`${resampledFileName}`);
        const targetChannel = client.channels.cache.get(SPECIFIC_CHANNEL_ID);
        const sentMessage = await targetChannel.send({ embeds: [embed], files: [audioFile] });

        // Upload data to Google Sheets
        const dateSubmitted = new Date();
        await sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
            spreadsheetId: SHEET_ID,
            range: `${TAB_APPROVED}!A1`,
            valueInputOption: 'RAW',
            resource: {
                values: [[
                    message.author.tag,
                    leadData.name,
                    leadData.whatsapp,
                    leadData.email,
                    leadData.age,
                    leadData.grad,
                    leadData.role,
                    analysisResult.ielts_score.overall,
                    analysisResult.ielts_score.pronunciation,
                    analysisResult.ielts_score.fluency,
                    analysisResult.ielts_score.grammar,
                    analysisResult.ielts_score.coherence,
                    analysisResult.ielts_score.vocabulary,
                    analysisResult.transcription,
                    dateSubmitted.toLocaleString(),
                    sentMessage.url,
                    'Yes'
                ]]
            }
        });

        fs.unlinkSync(resampledFileName); 
        await message.author.send('Thank you! Your lead has been submitted and recorded.');
    }
});

// Utility function to convert to WAV
// Helper function to convert audio to WAV format
async function convertToWav(inputPath, outputPath) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        ffmpeg(inputPath)
            .toFormat('wav')
            .on('end', resolve)
            .on('error', reject)
            .save(outputPath);
    });
}

// Helper function to resample audio to 16000 Hz


// Function to assess speech using the SpeechSuper API
async function assessSpeech(audioPath, questionPrompt) {
    const maxRetries = 3;
    let retries = 0;
    while (retries < maxRetries) {
        try {
            const apiKey = "";
            const url = `https://api.speechace.co/api/scoring/speech/v9/json?key=${apiKey}&dialect=en-us&user_id=XYZ-ABC-99001`;

            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('include_fluency', '1');
            formData.append('include_ielts_subscore', '1');
            formData.append('include_unknown_words', '1');
            formData.append('pronunciation_score_mode', 'strict');
            formData.append('relevance_context', questionPrompt);
            formData.append('user_audio_file', fs.createReadStream(audioPath));

            const response = await axios.post(url, formData, {
                headers: formData.getHeaders(),
            });

            const result = response.data;
            
            const scores = {
                ielts_score: {
                    overall: result.speech_score.cefr_score.overall || 'N/A',
                    pronunciation: result.speech_score.cefr_score.pronunciation || 'N/A',
                    fluency: result.speech_score.cefr_score.fluency || 'N/A',
                    grammar: result.speech_score.cefr_score.grammar || 'N/A',
                    coherence: result.speech_score.cefr_score.coherence || 'N/A',
                    vocabulary: result.speech_score.cefr_score.vocab || 'N/A',
                },
                relevance: {
                    class: result.speech_score.relevance.class || 'N/A'
                },
                transcription: result.speech_score.transcript || 'N/A',
            };

            const wordPronunciationDetails = result.speech_score.word_score_list.map(wordInfo => ({
                word: wordInfo.word || '',
                pronunciation: wordInfo.quality_score || 0,
            }));

            return {
                ...scores,
                word_pronunciation_details: wordPronunciationDetails
            };

        } catch (error) {
            retries += 1;
            console.error('Error during speech assessment:', error);
            console.log('Retrying...');
        }
    }
    throw new Error('Speech assessment failed after multiple attempts.');
}


// Login to Discord
client.login(DISCORD_TOKEN);

I dont know how to fix this issue but when i send a big audio file that happens it works fine with small ones

Based on what you've described and reading the error output, it is probably that the operation involving your large audio was aborted due to timeout. Could also be size limits for discord. You could try increasing the timeout  with:
const timeoutLimit = 60000 // 60 seconds

// For your get and post
const response = await axios.get(attachment.url, {
    responseType: 'arraybuffer',
    timeout: timeoutLimit
});

const response = await axios.post(url, formData, {
    headers: formData.getHeaders(),
    timeout: timeoutLimit
});

